# Can't find AWS lambda functions deployed by Amazon Lambda Tools for .NET in AWS Lambda functions list

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS and I am trying to develop my first lambda function with Visual Studio code.

I have created my Hello world Lambda function using Amazon Lambda Tools for .NET Core applications (4.3.0):

> dotnet new lambda.EmptyFunction helloworldcsharp.

After that i deployed it to my AWS account using

> dotnet lambda deploy-function helloworldcsharp

I got and success result and when i list my functions from the CLI I get the function listed back to me.

Going to the AWS web console on the other hand I can't see the lambda function listed among the others I created online.

[AWS Lambda Console functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm8Xd.png)

I thought I could be using a wrong profile but that is not the case since I see the roles I have in my account when I am deploying the function.

How can I "add" or list the functions created through Amazon lambda Tools for .NET in my account?
Am I doing something wrong and deploying it locally, somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure first in which region you have deployed your function (region is in your profile). And then select the same region at the top right corner in the AWS console.

Lambda is displayed per region.

Comment: Thank you TaiT's, that was indeed the case, I was looking at the wrong region.